# Seemingly identical Regex Apache RewriteRule... What is the difference?

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite, apache2

Dear folks,
Im trying to figure out what's the difference between these two

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*?)(-.*)?$   /$2?ln=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/([^/]+)(-.*)?$ /$2?ln=$1 [L]
```

They seem identical and both seem to work fine, but theres gotta be a difference...

Either of these should be installed to redirect with optional information behind the filename:

e.g. `en/something-to-love` >>  `something?ln=en`

Comment: Nice question. I hope it will help a bit to demistify RegEx.

Answer (score 2):

The `'.'` dot is overused and rarely needed. *Say what you mean and mean what you say!* Here's how I would write it:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/\-]+)(-[^/]*)?$ index.php?ln=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

While they might be similar, they're not *identical*:

- `.*?` - any character (lazy) *or none*,
- `[^/]+` - any character except a slash (`/`), *at least one*.

The second is not lazy, so you'll get `something-to-love?ln=en` (to get only `something`, add a question mark at the end: `[^/]+?`).

The choice between these two options depends on your needs.

Btw, you can shrink `[a-z][a-z]` to `[a-z]{2}`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference. Let us test both expressions on the string **aa/bbb/cccc/ddd/-eeeee**. The first one

```
^([a-z][a-z])/(.*?)(-.*)?$
```

will result in three match groups

```
1: (aa)
2: (bbb/cccc/ddd/)
3: (-eeeee)
```

while the second one `^([a-z][a-z])/([^/]+)(-.*)?$` will not match anything.

The key is that in the first expression you have `(.*?)(-.*)?` which means first group is anything until **-** is found. If **-** is matched then start the third group.

In the second expression you have `([^/]+)(-.*)?`, i.e., put everything till the **/** to the second group and then if **-** is matched, create a third group. The problem is with **not** matching **/** and starting new group with **-**.

If you test your second expression on two strings **aa/bbb-/eeeee** and **aa/bbb/-eeeee** you will see that only the first string will result in any matches

```
1: (aa)
2: (bbb)
3: (-/eeeee)
```

and the second will not.

Hope it helped.

Note: I have made all the mentioned tests at [www.RegexTester.com](http://www.regextester.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Apache is **lazy** by default. So in rewrite `.*` and `.*?` are equal. That's why your `[^/]+` is really `[^/]+?`.

You have no / after the initial one, so `[^/]` and `.` produce the same result.

As of `*` and `+`, you know that you will surely have something after the `en/` in your URL, so `*` is just broader, it will always be `+` (at least one character will follow the forward slash).

If you apply these facts its easy to see that they will work identically in your situation.

Comment: _"Apache is lazy by default."_ Where did you read that? I don't think so!

Comment: @ridgerunner Practive I guess. Or else `([^/]+)` would just eat the `-` character in the URL. - But if you're not conviced I can test it.